# Is there any way to make a pointer to a reference?

Tags: c++

Generally, I want to have a dynamic sized array that it's values are references to chars.

Is this possible?

Thanks

-- edit --

My goal was to have a pointer to an array of chars, where each char was a reference. The point of this was so that I could simply std::cout << the chars that were being pointed to. Something like this:

```
int main(){
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char *& word = ???;
    char[0] = &a;
}
```

I ended up realizing I could do the inverse:

```
int main(){
    char * a;
    char * b;
    char * word = new char[2];
    word[0] = 'a';
    word[1] = 'b';
    a = &word[0];
    b = &word[1];
    *a = 'c';
    std::cout << word << "\n";
}
```

So, problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: You'd need something like a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<char>>`, but it doesn't seem like the most favourable line of code.

Comment: Why would you want to store references in the array instead of the actual objects?

Comment: A pointer to a reference is impossible because its up to the compiler to decide whether a reference is a real value (/consumes memory)

Comment: I don't know what the problem is?? This works.. http://ideone.com/jOmMqQ But it's pointers to chars.. Not sure what you mean by "pointer to references".. Isn't all pointers "a pointer to a reference"? After all, you have to `&somevar`?? Why do you guys down-vote beginners.. Is that really a trend now? Does it make you feel better?

Comment: Thanks everyone. That all made sense. I ended up figuring out what I had to do to accomplish what I wanted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is disallowed by the language. From:

[www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

8.3.2.1:

> There shall be no references to references, *no arrays of references*,
>   and no pointers to references.

You will have to use pointers to chars instead.

Comment: Plus, references shall be initialized upon creation (and how do you do that in this case...).

Comment: @Damon You could use initializer lists, but it's still not allowed :-)